# Multiple conditions for do while loop

Tags: c, do-while

I am writing a currency converter in C.
I sat my loop to keep looping while the the user doesn't hit `'Q'` or `'q'`.
but it doesn't exit the loop if I use two conditions, only one condition is executed

Here is my code

```c
    do
    {
        .... some code....
       // then I ask user for option
        scanf("%c", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
            case 'U':
            case 'u':
                printf("Enter the amount in SAR: ");
                scanf("%f", &amount);
                printf("\n%.3f SAR => %.3f USD", amount, amount * 0.266667);
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                printf("Enter the amount in SAR: ");
                scanf("%f", &amount);
                printf("\n%.3f SAR => %.3f EURO", amount, amount * 0.273187);
                break;
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                break;
        }

    } while((option) != 'q' || 'Q');
```

Comment: Hint: What order are `!=` and `||` evaluated in?

Comment: You could first convert your input to lower case letter: `option = tolower(option);` right after reading the input. Then you do not have to care about upper case letter in your `switch` cases and also in the condition of your loop.

Comment: Agree with @Gerhardh If you always want to treat upper and lower case as the same then convert the input to either upper or lower case just after the `scanf`

Comment: But before you consider _flattening_ the user's selection, you might want to consider using the _case_ of their selection to differentiate between converting from SAR **to** USD or converting to SAR **from** USD... Eg 100.00SAR ~ $US26.66, Well, How many SAR would I get for $US100??? The dual functionality might be a winner!!! `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

The expression `while((option) != 'q' || 'Q')` will always be true because 'Q' is a value that is not zero (*false*).

You probably meant `while(option != 'q' && option != 'Q')`

Since Q/q is means the user wants out:

```
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            option = 'q';
            break;
    }

} while( option != 'q' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use logical operators on strings. You have to combine booleans. In this case you need the AND operator, because both conditions have to be true to continue the loop.

```c
...
} while(option != 'q' && option != 'Q')
```

Comment: or `while(tolower(option) != 'q')`